# How to achieve type safety in this example using a generic type?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```js
type A = {
  a: string;
  name: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
  name: string
}


function update<T extends A | B>(aOrB: T): T {
  return {...aOrB, name: "updated"}
}

const updatedA = update<A>({a: "a", name: "a"})
const updatedB = update<B>({b: "b", name: "B"})
```

How can we change this so that TypeScript can catch type errors within the `update` function?

Example type errors below that aren't being caught:

```js
function update<T extends A | B>(aOrB: T): T {
  return {...aOrB, b: 2, name: "updated"}
}
```

```js
function update<T extends A | B>(aOrB: T): T {
  return {...aOrB, foo: 2, name: "updated"}
}
```

I would expect that in each of the examples above that there would be a type error. In the first example, `b` is not guaranteed to exist, and if it does exist, it's a string, not a number. In the second, `foo` is not a field on either type.

Comment: Your problem cases are related to TS not having [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936). Similar to your problem, `interface X { p: string }; const x: X = {...{ p: '', extra: 1 }};` won't error - these "extra properties" errors only appear, if it's a literal in the most basic sense - otherwise, additional properties are fine for TS. It will however prevent you from accessing them, they are only problematic when iterating over properties, e.g. `Object.entries`, `for ... in`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. If it's not possible currently, then I'd accept that answer. It would also be helpful to know if there is another approach that can achieve the goal of having one function to handle two distinct types with one or more common properties while ensuring that only an `A` or `B` is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a generic type in the returned value, you can achieve it with a returned type `A|B`

Basically, a generic type cannot determine which type you want to have in the returned result, so you need to set a certain type for it

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  name: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
  name: string
}


function update<T extends A | B>(aOrB: T): (A|B) {
   return {...aOrB, b: 2, name: "updated"} //error
}

const updatedA = update<A>({a: "a", name: "a"})
const updatedB = update<B>({b: "b", name: "B"})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxpQkYC2EO%20x5VAviiqJFAEILJqAIyaFSlarQaiWZFB04AzAK4kAxsCIB7ElGVgAJhmAQAPABUoEAB4mSB3LCgAfPgD4AFBgDyBXjnMAShwPGGdeQMF0KAIIYGUCXSQAOlSfPwAaKBEoACYsqUYoACJ9IxMDYo4FNR18PUNjCAM4RDKm0xhPJGwSjGKC%20iLi-rZAlFqSevaK-jbGk1NebpzioQGaIZxi3irAoA)

Another way we can try is having `hasOwnProperty` to check property in the data, and then using them to cast to a proper type. It's kind of messy, but we would know types beforehand.

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  name: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
  name: string
}


function update<T extends A | B>(aOrB: T): (A|B) {
   if(aOrB.hasOwnProperty("b")) {
     return {...aOrB, a: "new", name: "updated"} as B //error
   }
   return {...aOrB, a: "new", name: "updated"} as A
}

const updatedA = update<A>({a: "a", name: "a"})
const updatedB = update<B>({b: "b", name: "B"})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxpQkYC2EO%20x5VAviiqJFAEILJqAIyaFSlarQaiWZFB04AzAK4kAxsCIB7ElGVgAJhmAQAPABUoEAB4mSB3LCgAfPgD4AFBgDyBXjnMAShwPGGdeQMF0KCJFL19eADoACwxcbwB3EgAFAi1IAlAPACIhYsDI1Gj0AghgZQJdJESWnz8AGkwcYpIIDOLOqUYoYv0jEwNitkxHfgB6OYgCPIJqKA5o2vrG5BbEtt5O7BHe-sH6YdHDYwhJ6bTYeU41HXw9a4m4RDGb0xhPJDHYoYAY0C7dEFsQIoF4kN4-Cb8b4fMy8AEiEZlc7SEa8KaBIA)

Comment: Oh, this is pretty close to perfect. Arbitrary fields cause a type error. Changing `b: 2` to `b: "2"` still allows the `b` field to exist, however.

Comment: Another problem is that I would like the type of the returned value to be determined by the generic type since _I think_ otherwise all downstream code wouldn't know which type is returned.

Comment: Because `b` is a property of `B`, we cannot know whether it's A or B beforehand, but you can have a property check with `hasOwnProperty` and then cast it. It's kind of messy but let me give you an example @RaphaelRafatpanah